# vertically align button & text, in IE language?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

As you can see in following screen shot, button goes up and text goes down.
How to fix this?

http://i53.tinypic.com/2yuizc2.png

Comment: note that "More" is a button 

(<input type=button>)

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left; height:auto">You Text</div>
    <div style="float:left; height:auto"><span>Your Button</span></div>
</div>
```

This should work fine with IE6, 7, 8..